# Disable HTML's required input onchange radio button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can you help me make it so that it does not check if the HIDDEN required input box is filled?

I have an order system that has a pickup and delivery radio button. 
When they choose Pickup, I have it it hidding the input boxes for Address, City, State, and zip. 
These boxes are required for delivery. Because they are required, it still checks if the boxes are filled, even when it is hidden.

The script function I have here works to hide the input boxes, but it will not let me move forward because it is still checking if the input box is filled or not.

```js
< script >
  function showFunctionDelivery() {
    var x = document.getElementById("deliveryStuff");
    var y = document.getElementById("pickupStuff");

    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";


    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";


    }
  }

function showFunctionPickup() {
  var x = document.getElementById("deliveryStuff");
  var y = document.getElementById("pickupStuff");

  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";



  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";


  }
} <
/script> <
script src = "assets/js/script.js" > < /script> < /
body >
```

```html
<body>

  <form action="/shipping" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Delivery/Pick Up</h1>
      <hr>
      <input onchange="showFunctionDelivery()" type="radio" class="form-group" id="delivery" name="delivery" checked> Delivery &nbsp
      <input onchange="showFunctionPickup()" type="radio" class="form-group" id="pickup" name="delivery"> Pick Up &nbsp
      <br>
      <!---Needed for order name, date time.-->
      <div class="row" id="pickupStuff">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          Name: ex. John Smith
          <input required type="text" pattern="\D+" id="name" class="form-control" value="" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          Desired Date:
          <input required type="date" id="date" class="form-control" name="date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="time">
          Desired Time:
          <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="7am">7am</option>
                        <option value="8am">8am</option>
                        <option value="9am">9am</option>
                        <option value="10am">10am</option>
                        <option value="11am">11am</option>
                        <option value="12pm">12pm</option>
                        <option value="1pm">1pm</option>
                        <option value="2pm">2pm</option>
                        <option value="3pm">3pm</option>
                        <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    </select>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!--delivery stuff-->
    <div class="container" id="deliveryStuff">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="deliveryOp">
          Address: ex. 12345 Plain Dr
          <input required type="text" id="address" pattern="\d+\s\D+" class="form-control" value="" name="address">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="deliveryOp">
          City: ex. Austin
          <input required type="text" id="city" pattern="\D+" class="form-control" value="" name="city">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="deliveryOp">
          State:
          <select required class="form-control" id="state" name="statename">
                        <option value="">Please Select One</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AR">Etc.</option>
                        
                    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="deliveryOp">
          Zip Code: ex. 12345
          <input required id="zip" type="text" pattern="\d{5}" class="form-control" value="" name="zipcode">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><br><br>

    <script>
      let d = document.getElementById("delivery"),
        p = document.getElementById("pickup");
    </script>
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
      <a href="/billing"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Next</button></a>
    </footer>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: While I wouldn't recommend making the fields required based on the display attribute, you should be able to write `x.required = false`, assuming `x` is your input that you want disabled and not required.

Answer (score 1):

Set required attribute of address, city, state and ZIP code to false in `showFunctionPickUp()` method.

```
    function showFunctionPickup() {
      var x = document.getElementById("deliveryStuff");
      var y = document.getElementById("pickupStuff");
      var address = document.getElementById("address");
      var city = document.getElementById("city");
      var state = document.getElementById("state");
      var zip = document.getElementById("zip");

      x.style.display = "none";
      address.required = false;
      city.required = false;
      state.required = false;
      zip.required = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `removeAttr()` methos to remove the `required` attribute. You can use it as follows:

```
$("#address").removeAttr('required');
```

To add the required fields again, use the `attr()` method as

```
$("#address").attr('required','');
```